# ARC and Popovers and delegates

Tags: delegates, automatic-ref-counting, uipopovercontroller, popover

i am tearing my hair out, I have migrated my old project to arc and I'm getting this error popping up : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.'

I have read through some threads and I'm confused, some say when using delegates use a weak reference but on the other hand when using popovers use a strong property reference, can someone give me an example of how best to use ARC and delegates with a popover that has a button inside that changes the background colour for example?

From what I've read I keep hearing use an instance variable in my view controller, here it is in my main view controller:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *currentPopover;
```

and the is the method implementation in the main view controller file:

```
- (IBAction)ShowPopTextColor:(id)sender {

if (currentPopover == nil) {

TimerTextColor *timerTextColor = [[TimerTextColor alloc]init];
timerTextColor.delegate =self;
UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController                  alloc]initWithContentViewController:timerTextColor];
[pop setDelegate:self];
    [pop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 240)];
[pop presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

//[pop release];

} else {

   [currentPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    currentPopover = nil;
}

}
```

here is my popup content header:

```
@protocol colorChooserDelegate

-(void) colorSelected:(UIColor*)thecolor;

@end

@interface TimerTextColor : UIViewController{

id<colorChooserDelegate> delegate;

IBOutlet UIButton *colorView;

}

- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id) sender;
@property (nonatomic,strong) id<colorChooserDelegate>delegate;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIButton *colorView;

@end
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign currentPopover.
Call

```
currentPopover = pop
```

after popover creation

Comment: Thanks! My focus was on arc and I was blindsighted ! This code worked before arc so I didn't even think about assigning my local back to my instance variable ! Thanks again for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't create a local variable to store the popover controller.

Change this

```
UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:timerTextColor];
```

to

```
self.currentPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:timerTextColor];
```